# How can I replace missing variables from scope with some default values?

Tags: javascript, eval, mathjs

I'm using mathjs for calculating some expressions from JSON data. I call eval, where I pass JSON data as a scope. I can use JSON paths in the mathjs script, like user1.age > user2.age. But when these paths are not contained in JSON, mathjs throws an error.

If the symbol is null, I can easily check it in the mathjs script. But if it is undefined, I cannot do it, because mathjs throws error, instead of evaluating it to undefined.

```
left == null ? right : left
```

This script evaluates to 42 for the following input -

```
{
  "left": null,
  "right": 42
}
```

But throws an error "Error: Undefined symbol left" for this -

```
{
  "right": 42
}
```

Tried to traverse expression tree, and add all of the missing symbols to the JSON data, and pass it to the eval later. 
https://mathjs.org/examples/advanced/expression_trees.js.html
But is there a better way for custom symbols handling?